# ORA-01407: cannot update a field to NULL in DB

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am trying to delete few rows from the table -cost_mdl_ver_equip but I am getting the following error:

```
delete from tbcam.cost_mdl_ver_equip where mdl_ver_id = 303165
```

Error:

```
Error starting at line : 10 in command -
delete from tbcam.cost_mdl_ver_equip where mdl_ver_id = 303165
Error report -
ORA-01407: cannot update ("TBCAM"."COST_MDL_VER_EQUIP"."MDL_VER_ID") to NULL
```

Here is the constraints for the table:
[image]

what fix do I need to do?

Comment: seems you have a delete trigger for `cost_mdl_ver_equip` table.

Comment: which trigger should I remove? to make the delete happen

Comment: @sromit if you look under your tablespace in SQL Developer there is a section that shows triggers that have been defined. Have a look in there for any that reference this table.

Comment: Was that the complete error message? I would have expected it to include the trigger name and the line number from the trigger that actually threw the error. I wouldn't recommend that you remove (or disable) the trigger though, without fully understanding what it is doing and why.

Comment: I checked the Trigger section in sql-developer..there is nothing there, at least not related to this table..Yeah thats all the error message it shows

Comment: Right. Actually... it looks like it might be related to the one of the FKs  that has an 'on delete set null' action? You may be deleting a parent value and it's trying to null a child. Dig into which columns those constraints apply to, perhaps.

Comment: You actually posted an image of all the constraints on your table. The issue must be a FK that points back to the same table (since the error message is referencing the same table from which you are trying to delete). The image shows exactly one FK that points back to the same table - and, indeed, as Alex Poole conjectured, it has the `set null` option on delete. That's your issue. With your end user's hat on, think whether the `delete` you wanted to perform should be allowed in the first place, since it seems it will perturb other things in the same table.

Comment: so I have to go the child table and make 'on delete no action' ..but shouldnt it tell me the name of the child_table.column name on which it is trying to null it. The error is giving the parent_table.column_name only

Comment: @mathguy, you are right on spot..yeah..I will analyze the impact..but for now if we make the ```on delete no action```..my query should run right

Comment: The child table is the parent table itself. I don't know your data model, but this is common, for example, in an employee table, where every manager is also an employee on their own.

Comment: I am not sure what "on delete no action" means. Perhaps it means "don't delete after all"? In which case, yes, you can run your `delete` statement - and it won't delete anything.

Comment: ok..got it....if I remove the FK..then it will allow me to delete

Comment: But presumably it's there for a reason. Possibly you need to delete the child records first instead, or update them to a different parent ID, if that's appropriate. We don't know your data or model, so I'd suggest you ask someone who does (e.g. your DBA) before you do anything drastic.

Comment: Don't go deleting table constraints or FKs. These are enforcing business rules for data integrity. If the delete doesn't work then go back and get clarification on how to make it work within the rules. Removing the constraints and forcing the delete will likely end up with a data integrity failure that may be much harder to fix.

Comment: sure of course...I have connected with the DBA for that..I am just looking at the options